# Existence of a morphism between spectrum of fields whose induced diagram commutative.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It seems a basic question and I stuck at making rigorous proof.

Let $\alpha : Y' \to Y$ be a morphism of scheme. Let $y' \in Y'$ and $y\in Y$ be points such that $\alpha(y')=y$. Let $c_y : \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(y) \to Y$ and $c'_{y'} : \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(y') \to Y'$ be the canonical morphisms.

Then does there exists a morphism $\beta:\operatorname{Spec}\kappa(y') \to \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(y)$ such that $\alpha \circ c'_{y'}=c_y\circ\beta$ (the diagram commutative)?

I have a motivation for this question but it is somewhat long, so first of all I upload question only.

Can anyone helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assume that $Y$ and $Y'$ are affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec}A, \operatorname{Spec}A'$. Moreover $y\in Y, y'\in Y$ correspond to ${\frak p}\subset A,{\frak p'}\subset A' $.

Then if $\alpha': Y'\to Y$ correspond to $\phi: A\to A'$, then $\phi^{-1}({\frak p'})={\frak p}$.

Now we can construct homomorphism $k({\frak p})\to k({\frak p'})$ induced by $\phi$. This is your desired map.

Comment: O.K. Thanks ! ~